# CSS effect like Cinemax logo (angle ends of background)

Tags: css, transform

I have tilted text and a background using `-webkit-transform: rotate(-#deg);` and `background` selectors, but the ends of the background stay perpendicular to the text. How can I customize the degree at which the ends are cut off (à la the Cinemax logo).

[image: Cinemax]

I've tried putting the span in a parent div to cut off the edges, but it's tricky. What's the best way to angle the ends of the background in CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the `rotate`, you should also `skew` your element:

```
div {
    transform: rotate(-5deg) skew(-10deg);
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VANrX/

Comment: Didn't even know `skew` existed. Thanks so much

Comment: Here is a fiddle with the little shadow just in case you wanted that: http://jsfiddle.net/VANrX/6/

Comment: @IlanBiala `box-shadow: 10px 6px 0px -3px goldenrod;` is closer to the actual logo shadow

Comment: I'm just giving the code, I'm sure Sean isn't planning on using that golden color.